# Laravel Flatten: Empty Cache by values in Saltshaker

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4, flatten

I have a Laravel Project, which renders hundreds of websites. The Content is provided by a back-end System. To increase the Performance i want to cache the complete HTML with the Anahkiasen\Flatten module.
To generate for each Website an own cache, i added a combination of three values into the `saltshaker` Array in the Flatten config.

My Problem is, how i can clear the cache by the three values, so the cache is cleared for a single website instead of all hundreds. 
I tried to clear the cache with `\Flatten::flushUrl()` because all Websites has their own sub-Domain. But the cache wasn't cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the hash is generated from the values in `saltshaker` Array with the additional information of HTTP Request Type and the Route. 
So this script worked for me, because i only have a single cached route:

```
$pages = $cached = (array) $this->app['flatten.storage']->get('cached');
$hash = $this->app['flatten']->computeHash('/');

foreach ($pages as $key => $page) {
    if ($hash === $page) {
        $this->app['cache']->forget($page);
        unset($cached[$key]);
    }
}

$this->app['flatten.storage']->set('cached', $cached);
```